# MiBPHP Fatal error While compiling

Tags: magento2

getting the following error when compiling

MiBPHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class Less_Version in /home/public_html/app/code/Plazathemes/Layout/Block/lib/Less/Version.php on line 9

Version.php code

```
<?php

/**
 * Release numbers
 *
 * @package Less
 * @subpackage version
 */
class Less_Version{

        const version = '1.7.0.10';                     // The current build number of less.php
        const less_version = '1.7.0';           // The less.js version that this build should be compatible with
        const cache_version = '170';            // The parser cache version

}
```

I am using PHP 5.6.11-1ubuntu3.4 on Ubuntu 15.10

Currently running Magento 2.1